# Calendar subtract date issue

Tags: java, date, parsing, calendar, printwriter

I have an almost finished script, but there is one slight hiccup of which I can't seem to fix.

First of let me quickly explain the script. It gets the current date using `Calendar`. Then it adds 2 days to that current date, after that it creates a format, to change the format of the new date. It then prints that new date to a .txt file, afterwards it then gets that date from the .txt file by using a `Scanner`. It is then here, where I am having some slight trouble. That new date of which I have gotten from the .txt file, I would like to subtract from the actual current date. Thus I would be able to have a countdown from the current system date and until 2 days from that. Currently the code is subtracting using the date variable `todAdd` within the subtraction/countdown function which is the last 6 lines of the code. But instead of it being that date variable, I would like it to be the `dateFroText` variable, but I am unable to parse it to that last subtraction code as it doesn't seem to be handling the parsing of the variable very well.

So basically to give an example I would like the whole countdown part to have the `todAdd` changed with the `dateFroText`. So instead of the lines you seen in the full code below it would be like this `int yearDiff = dateFroText.get(Calendar.YEAR) - startDat.get(Calendar.YEAR);`

Currently I have tried changing it to an `integer`, a `string` and `date` but all of them generate one error, which makes it impossible to run the code.

If necessary I have copied the whole code, so you are able to actually test it.

```
public class CdowTDate
{

    static File dFileD = new File("date.txt");
    static String date = "";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

      //Get current date and time
      Calendar startDat = Calendar.getInstance();
      System.out.println("Current date: " + startDat.getTime());

      //Get that current date and time and then add 2 days
      Calendar todAdd = Calendar.getInstance();
      todAdd.add(Calendar.DATE, 2);
      System.out.println("Date in 2 days: " + todAdd.getTime());

      //Create a format for sending date to text file
      SimpleDateFormat formDat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
      String formatted = formDat.format(todAdd.getTime());
      System.out.println("Formatted: " + formatted);

      try{
          PrintWriter dW = new PrintWriter("date.txt");
          dW.println(formatted);
          dW.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
      }

      System.out.println(formDat.parse(formatted));

      try {
          Scanner dateRead = new Scanner(dFileD);
          while (dateRead.hasNextLine()) {
              date = dateRead.nextLine();
              Date dateFroText = formDat.parse(date);
              System.out.println("Date from text new format: " + dateFroText);
          }
          dateRead.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error!");
        }

      int yearDiff = todAdd.get(Calendar.YEAR) - startDat.get(Calendar.YEAR);
      int dayDiff = ((yearDiff*365) + todAdd.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)) - startDat.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
      dayDiff--;
      int hourDiffer = todAdd.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+23 - startDat.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
      int minuDiff = todAdd.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+60 - startDat.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
      System.out.println(dayDiff + " days " + hourDiffer + " hours " + minuDiff +" minutes remaining");


  }

}
```

Comment: Please post your error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the date object dateFroTxt to a Calendar object to do the calculation.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        //Get current date and time
        Calendar startDat = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println("Current date: " + startDat.getTime());

        //Get that current date and time and then add 2 days
        Calendar todAdd = Calendar.getInstance();
        todAdd.add(Calendar.DATE, 2);
        System.out.println("Date in 2 days: " + todAdd.getTime());

        //Create a format for sending date to text file
        SimpleDateFormat formDat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
        String formatted = formDat.format(todAdd.getTime());
        System.out.println("Formatted: " + formatted);

        try {
            PrintWriter dW = new PrintWriter("date.txt");
            dW.println(formatted);
            dW.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        System.out.println(formDat.parse(formatted));

        Date dateFroText = null;
        try {
            Scanner dateRead = new Scanner(dFileD);
            while (dateRead.hasNextLine()) {
                date = dateRead.nextLine();
                dateFroText = formDat.parse(date);
                System.out.println("Date from text new format: " + dateFroText);
            }
            dateRead.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error!");
        }

        if (dateFroText != null) {
            Calendar dateFromTxtCal = Calendar.getInstance();
            dateFromTxtCal.setTime(dateFroText);
            int yearDiff = dateFromTxtCal.get(Calendar.YEAR) - startDat.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int dayDiff = ((yearDiff * 365) + dateFromTxtCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)) - startDat.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
            dayDiff--;
            int hourDiffer = dateFromTxtCal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + 23 - startDat.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minuDiff = dateFromTxtCal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + 60 - startDat.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            System.out.println(dayDiff + " days " + hourDiffer + " hours " + minuDiff + " minutes remaining");
        }
    }
```